# Stuck trying to create a react.js app in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-2019

I am following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-nodejs-with-react-and-jsx?view=vs-2019) to create a react.js application in visual studio

I am at the step where it says to open the command prompt and run:

```
webpack app.tsx --config webpack-config.js
```

(I am already in the node_modules.bin\ directory)

I get the error:

> C:\Users\user.user\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2019\Projects\WeatherApp\WeatherApp\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:11
>   const runCommand = (command, args) => {
>                                       ^ module.js:434   var compiledWrapper = runInThisContext(wrapper, filename, true);
>                           ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
>       at Module._compile (module.js:434:25)
>       at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
>       at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
>       at Array.0 (module.js:484:10)
>       at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:190:38)

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "weather-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "WeatherApp",
  "main": "server.js",
  "author": {
    "name": ""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "prettier": "^1.17.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "ts-loader": "^5.4.4",
    "typescript": "^3.3.4000",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0"
  }
}
```

The versions are more recent than what is indicated in the tutorial, otherwise I have done everything as indicated. I have node.js 10.15.3 installed on my machine.

The contents of the tsconfig.json file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "pretty": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "files": [
        "app.tsx"
    ]
}
```

webpack-config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: "./app.tsx",
    mode: "development",
    output: {
        filename: "./app-bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.Webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js', '.jsx', '.tsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'ts-loader'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to resolve and or troubleshoot this. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you by chance have a legacy version of node.js installed rather than a modern one?

Comment: @WiktorZychla I have Latest LTS Version: 10.15.3 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured this out and don't really particularly care for this solution, but it works for now. I suppose it has to do with which directory you are running the bundle script from. However, now if I get updates it will likely overwrite this. Also, I have to run the bundle command from the project directory, not the .bin.

In the .bin folder I altered the scripts for `webpack-cli.cmd` and `webpack.cmd`

Webpack.cmd from:

```
@IF EXIST "c:\program files\nodejs\node.exe" (
```

> "%~dp0\node.exe"

```
 "%~dp0\..\webpack\bin\webpack.js" %*    
    ) ELSE (
      @SETLOCAL
      @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
      node  "%~dp0\..\webpack\bin\webpack.js" %*

    )
```

to:

```
@IF EXIST "c:\program files\nodejs\node.exe" (
```

> "c:\program files\nodejs\node.exe"

```
 "%~dp0\..\webpack\bin\webpack.js" %*    
    ) ELSE (
      @SETLOCAL
      @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
      node  "%~dp0\..\webpack\bin\webpack.js" %*          
    )
```

webpack-cli.cmd from:

```
@IF EXIST "c:\program files\nodejs\node.exe" (
```

> "%~dp0\node.exe"

```
  "%~dp0\..\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js" %*
    ) ELSE (
      @SETLOCAL
      @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
      node  "%~dp0\..\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js" %*
```

to:

```
@IF EXIST "c:\program files\nodejs\node.exe" (
```

> "c:\program files\nodejs\node.exe"

```
  "%~dp0\..\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js" %*
    ) ELSE (
      @SETLOCAL
      @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
      node  "%~dp0\..\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js" %*
```